# How to delete part of R studio console?

Tags: r, console, rstudio

I don't want to erase the entire console, but just a few lines (as I have to submit my Rcode as an assignment and if I make an error, I want to be able to edit/clean up my coding). Thanks!

Comment: Just run the code again without the error after cleaning the console? And why would you include console output when submitting R code? Just include your script.

Comment: Don't do your work directly in the console. Use a script windows. To run code, just hit the "run" button.

Comment: It might take talking with the teacher, but you can use [R notebooks](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html) to submit R code and its output, with a much cleaner interface. If something goes wrong in a "chunk" of code, just update it and re-run, and the output is now clean.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

use R editor from **File** option.
type script in the R editor and run each line by selecting it and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

if you have typed it in console directly then you can still copy your typed script form the console and paste it in the editor

Comment: I think the question was specifically about RStudio, not the Rgui.

Comment: i think similar could also be done in R studio but the problem didn't specify whether it's Rgui or R studio